# FFmpeg / Create video / Add caption (timestamp) of each jpg file to generate mp4

Tags: video, text, ffmpeg, screenshot, caption

I've got some pictures, as screenshot-1.jpg, ..., screenshot-345.jpg, cycle of automatic capture from my computer (cycle of 30 seconds). I use FFmpeg to generate a video mp4 format, but, I want to add on the video the timestamp of each jpg file.

This is my command line of FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -r 4 -i screenshot-%0d.jpg -b 512000 -s 3840x1200 -sameq video.mp4
```

In this case, I can show the date/time during de video play.

*Thanks.
Low*

Comment: are you able to use visual studio? Some time ago had same problem and I just made a simple C# application for that using the API. I remember it was quite simple, but don't have the code anymore. :(

Comment: http://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/

Comment: No, but I can think about my screenshot, to add the timestamp as watermark directly during the process, but, I use autoit to generate the screenshot, and the function to add a text during the screenshot process is not available (not exist).
Thinking about it (or another solutions), and if I found them, I post here.
Thanks.

Comment: @low Unrelated to your question, but why are you using `-sameq`? It does not mean "same quality" and is not designed to be used between formats that do not share the quantizer scale.

Comment: I'm a noob using FFmpeg, and, without this _option_, the result of the video is horrible, artifact artifact artifact everywhere, a pixel soup.
If you know an option to create a lossless video without using `-sameq`, why not, I using FFmpeg since a few days now.

_Have a good day !_